# Find limit of two interrelated sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

The sequences are defined as follows:

$$a_0=1=s_0$$
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{s_{n}}-\sqrt{2}$$
$$s_{n+1}=s_{n}+a_{n+1}$$

Goal is to find its limits and prove that they exist.

Comment: Nothing extraordinary. I was trying to find if it's possible to reduce these two sequences to one. Next I was trying to make approximations of these two sequences in hope for using the squeezing theorem.
I was also trying to find out some recurrent definition for two of these sequences alone, basing on how first elements look like.

Comment: Well, there's always $$a_{n+1}=\frac 1 {\sum_0^n a_k} - \sqrt 2$$.

Comment: @SekstusEmpiryk, After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$s_{n+1}=s_n+\frac{1}{s_n}-\sqrt{2} $$
converges to the fixed point $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, since $\{s_{2n}\}$ is a decreasing sequence and $\{s_{2n+1}\}$ is an increasing sequence. As a consequence, $a_n\to 0$.

Comment: Thanks for hint. It was easy to show that those two subsequences have limits. It was much harder (in respect of needed calculations) to show that this is the same limit.

Comment: Both $\{s_{2n}\}$ and $\{s_{2n+1}\}$ are monotonic and bounded, so $s_{2n}\to A$ and $s_{2n+1}\to B$, with $B=f(A)$ and $A=f(B)$, where $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}-\sqrt{2}$. It is not difficult to check that $A=B$ is needed.